# BQ (Big Query) - Modify JSON output, to be accepted by BQ

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Currently, using API to collect JSON file. I have managed to extract this output as I demonstrated below.

And now I'm on the stage, that I have JSON extraction and need to make in the way that BQ will accept it. Without too much manipulation ( as this output potentially will be loaded on the daily bases.

```
{
    "stats": [{
            "date": "2018-06-17T00:00:00.000Z",
            "scores": {
                "my-followers": 8113,
                "my-listed": 15,
                "my-favourites": 5289,
                "my-followings": 230,
                "my-statuses": 3107
            }
        }, {
            "date": "2018-06-18T00:00:00.000Z",
            "scores": {
                "my-statuses": 3107,
                "my-followings": 230,
                "my-lost-followings": 0,
                "my-new-followers": 0,
                "my-new-statuses": 0,
                "my-listed": 15,
                "my-lost-followers": 5,
                "my-followers": 8108,
                "my-favourites": 5288,
                "my-new-followings": 0
            }
        }
        .....
    ],
    "uid": "123456789"
}
```

ANy help will be appreciated.

Currently I have this error:

```
Errors:
query: Invalid field name "my-new-followings". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long. Table: link_t_perf_test1_b58d4465_3a31_40cb_987f_9fb2d1de29dc_source (error code: invalidQuery
```

Even when "my-new-followings" contain only integer (up to 5 digit) number.

Comment: What exactly is your question!? :)

Comment: @GrahamPolley I need that this JSON will be acceptable by BQ ( so that I could upload it and "Automatically schema detection" can be used)...

Comment: @GrahamPolley Have updated question ( with an error )

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: you can't have a field name with a dash in it.